how to obfuscate code in package androidx
like this i create java class in package androidx.test.
nowing it just obfuscate classmember,classMethod. but i want it also obfuscate classname. how can obfuscate it？


here is my proguard:
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-verbose
-dontpreverify
-ignorewarnings
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,EnclosingMethod
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-optimizationpasses 5
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/,!class/merging/
-dontwarn **
-printseeds proguard/seeds.txt
-printusage proguard/unused.txt
-keepattributes Signature
